# mysql.connector connection issues with windows auth

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I want to connect to a database via windows auth.

I tried the library pyodbc and I don't have an issues using following code:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=<server>;'
                      'Database=<dbname>;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

However, I cannot connect via mysql.connector or sqlachemy. Are there any specific packages I need?

I tried the following code, but it did not work:

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://<server>/<dbname>?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0', echo=True)
```

I got the following error code:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Der Datenquellenname wurde nicht gefunden, und es wurde kein Standardtreiber angegeben (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
```

which translates into: DNS was not found and no standard drivers were given

Available odbc drivers:

- Driver da Microsoft para arquivos texto (*.txt; *.csv)
- Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)
- Driver do Microsoft dBase (*.dbf)
- Driver do Microsoft Excel(*.xls)
- Driver do Microsoft Paradox (*.db )
- Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
- Microsoft Access-Treiber (*.mdb)
- Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)
- Microsoft dBase-Treiber (*.dbf)
- Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)
- Microsoft Excel-Treiber (*.xls)
- Microsoft ODBC for Oracle
- Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )
- Microsoft Paradox-Treiber (*.db )
- Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)
- Microsoft Text-Treiber (*.txt; *.csv)
- SQL Server
- Oracle in OraClient120102_32bit

Comment: MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server are two completely different products. It should not be surprising that MySQL Workbench does not work with Microsoft SQL Server. Also, simply saying that something "did not work" is not a sufficient description of the issue. Did you get an error message? If so, what did it say? Please [edit] your question to provide more information.

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what drivers are available to your Python app.

Comment: see edited post. thanks for your help

Comment: The list indicates that you are running 32-bit Python but you do not have "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" installed, at least not a 32-bit version.